# Executing a Javascript function from Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am attempting to call a javascript function on a particular page from my global.asax file, as demonstrated below. I have read in other forums that this is possible using the method below. However, I am struggling to get this to work. I am not receiving any errors in the console, however the function is simply not executing. The function does work as expected and can be called from the page on which it is created without any issues. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Application_AcquireRequestState(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
            Dim currentPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()

            If Not currentPage.ToLower().Contains("Online/default.aspx") Then
                If HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID") Is Nothing Then

                    Dim MyPage As System.Web.UI.Page

                    MyPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler

                    MyPage.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(MyPage.GetType(), "MyScriptKey", "function f(){closeWin(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);", True)

                    Session.Abandon()
                    Response.Redirect("~/")
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: One thing to note: you call `ToLower()` and then check to see if an upper case letter is in the string... ;). You have a `Response.Redirect` at the end of this, so your client script will not have a chance to run, since the browser will receive a 302 response, which are not rendered.

Comment: `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is just registering the script on the page, in other words adding it. It isn't "calling" the function `f` that your script defines. To do that you'll need to use some client script on the page. This page explains how RegisterClientScriptBlock works -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @sh1rts is correct, try calling f() at the end: `MyPage.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(MyPage.GetType(), "MyScriptKey", "function f(){closeWin(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f); f();", True)`